# How to show leading space in `` element?

Tags: support, markdown

https://superuser.com/a/1007567/298426 shows that it'd be useful to have a leading space (in the `rm -rf *` element). Yet, no matter how many spaces one adds in the beginning, i.e.

```
` rm -rf *`
`  rm -rf *`
`   rm -rf *`
...
```

doesn't make them displayed.

Even large [markdown tutorials](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) don't cover this issue.

Comment: Useful how? The post reads well to me as is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this enough spaces for you?

`rm -rf *`

Use HTML:

`<code>                 rm -rf *</code>`

Alternatively, you can use a series of spaced back ticks:

`rm -rf *`

Like this:

`` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` `rm -rf *` ``

Note that neither of these work in comments.

I have found something that works as long as it is between visible characters in comments. It's the soft hyphen:

`­   ­   ­   ­  ­  ­ rm -rf *`

(It doesn't seem to need the leading character in posts, however.)

Alternatively, in normal text, you can just use the left to right mark:

‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ­  ­ rm -rf *

That works in comments too!

Comment: `. ­  ­  ­  ­  ­  ­  ­  ­  ­ rm -rf *`

Comment: ­ ‎ ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎  ‎ rm -rf *

Answer (score 5):

Markdown is limited to what it can handle. `*This*`, for example, is the proper way to indicate emphasis; then, what ought `* this*` translate to?

For all things not covered by Markdown, you can fallback to   `ye olde HTML`  . It seems this even supports multiple spaces!

*source:*

```
For all things not covered by Markdown, you can fallback to
<code>  ye olde HTML  </code>. It seems this even supports multiple spaces!
```